# 802.11 Duration Field Reset to 0 By Wireless Driver

Tags: wifi, drivers, 802.1x

I am trying to send out custom, raw 802.11 frames using an Alfa AWUS036H with USB driver rtl8187. This is possible using tcpreplay, hexinject, or a number of other Linux utilities. A custom PCAP file can be created, and 'replayed' over the air.

I have modified the 802.11 header in a packet to meet my needs, but when I send the packet, it seems that the wireless driver is modifying the duration field that I specified, because duration field is updated according to the actual packet length before it is sent. For my application, I need the duration to be set to a specific value.

I am verifying what packet is actually sent out by capturing the packet with another wireless adapter and Wireshark.

Has anyone been able to transmit raw 802.11 frames? If so, what hardware/software was used?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it was indeed the rtl8187 driver that was modifying the duration field. The driver was calculating the duration and replacing my custom duration with the calculated one. I had to edit the driver code and recompile it in order to transmit the raw 802.11 frame like I wanted. Once the driver code was modified, any of the utilities mentioned in the question worked for transmitting.